# getting the object passed as an argument to a stubbed method with Mocha

Tags: ruby, mocking, stubbing, ruby-mocha

```
Foo.expects(:bar)
Foo.bar(:abc => 123, :xyz => 987)

# assert Foo.bar was called with a hash that has a key of :abc == 123
```

Basically I want to examine the object passed as an argument to a stubbed method, in order to inspect on a value of that object.  In my situation I can't use `Foo.expects(:bar).with({:abc => 123})` because I know the object wont equal each other.  I just want to compare a sub-value of the argument.

Surely this is possible, I just can't find the syntax or strategy here.

Answer (score 25):

I figured it out!  Turns out `with` can take a block.

```
Foo.expects(:bar).with do |the_hash|
  the_hash[:abc] == 123
end
```